# Получить данные о пользователе в шаблон по user из url django

Tags: django, url, request

На сайте авторизован User0, он находиться на странице со своими постами (site.ru/User0/posts), он переходит на страницу site.ru/User1/posts для просмотра записей User1.
Знаю, что из адреса site.ru/User1/post можно достать username в шаблон вот так

```
{{ request.resolver_match.kwargs.username }}
```

Подскажите, а как можно достать данные пользователя user1 (currentuser = user0) вне цикла вывода записей.
Примерно в шаблоне так:

```
{{ user1.username }} {{ user1.nickname }}
{% for post in posts %}
   выводяться посты user1
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял Ваш вопрос, Вам следует в классе или функции представления добавить в контекст автора постов  (User) и дальше можно обращаться к нему вне цикла.

```
def post_author_view(request, username):
    # Получаем пользователя-автора постов по username из URL
    author = User.objects.get(username=username)
    
    context = {
        'author': author,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'post_author_template.html', context)
```